# Clean Dynamic field in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

In my admin field, i've created an Input hidden field after ajax request. Now i want to see in my Model whether this field exists or not so that i can raise validation error.

```
class Vehicle(Model):
  ....

  def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
    if self.cleaned_data.get('VIN_error') is not None:
            raise ValidationError({
                'VIN': ValidationError(_('Invalid VIN.'), code='invalid'),
            })
```

I am not sure which method should I use to see if VIN_error field exists in my view. Currently i am getting

> object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Please note that VIN_error only exist in view not in the model.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing model valuation, the recommended approach is to override the `clean` method, not `clean_fields`. You don't have access to `cleaned_data`, but you can access the object being validated with `self`.

If you need access to cleaned data from the view, that belongs in your form or model form's validation.

Comment: Sorry, how do i access the object with self?

Comment: In the model's `clean` method, `self` is the object, so `self.name` would give you the vehicle's name. There's an example [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean).